# Echo text with html caracters in table HTML

Tags: php, html

I need to print a string with HTML caracters like `'<sometext>'`. 
And when its has `<br />` its needs to print spaces, like tag `<br />`.
So I have this code:

```
$descricao = str_replace("%q", " < ",
                          str_replace("%w", " > ",
                             str_replace("%s", "<br />",
                               preg_replace('/(\<)/', '%q',
                                 preg_replace('/(\>)/', '%w',
                                     preg_replace('/(\<br \/\>)/', '%s', $pr->descricao)
                                     )
                                 )
                               )
                             )
                         );
```

That is works fine, but its so confused. 
Is have something short and readable?

Example:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br /> <consectetur>";
<table>
  <tr><td>echo $string</td></tr>
</table>
```

I need to show like that

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
<consectetur>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br /> <consectetur>";

$string = str_replace("\n", "<br />", 
                    htmlentities(
                        str_replace("<br />", "\n", $string)
                    ) 
                ); 

echo $string;
```

Comment: Perfect. I just change the htmlentities to htmlspecialchars.